# How can I do an alias in local

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, alias

I have a Mac server with Apache.

I would like reach `127.0.0.1/mywebsite` by an **alias** in local, for example : myweb.

How could i do for it ? 
Use httpd.conf ?

I'm waiting for your anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a virtual host like explained [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/).

You have to edit

> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

and

> /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your /etc/hosts file and add an alias, but you'd still have to add the path if there's no root index.

I tried this in my hosts file and it worked perfectly.

```
127.0.0.1      myweb
```

You'll also need to flush your DNS cache with a

```
sudo killall mDNSResponder
```